# Get name of powershell shortcut

Tags: windows, powershell

I know that `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` returns the script name, but how would I get the name of the shortcut that targets the script?

Comment: The script do not have any relationship with the shortcut. If you have multiple shortcuts and you want to determine which one was used. I suggest that you use parameters/command line arguments. Example `script.ps1 -shortcut shortcut1`

Comment: Why does it matter?